# Stream stdout logs from Go EC2 Environment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Go application running in an EC2 instance. Log streaming is enabled and I am able to view the default `ed-activity.log`, `nginx/access.log` and `nginx/error.log` in the CloudWatch console.

However, the application is logging to `stdout` but I cannot see these logs within CloudWatch. I know they're because stored as I can download the full logging bundle and see them.

The question is how can I get these logs into CloudWatch? I have a .NET application and it's stdout logs appear in CloudWatch fine.